# Расположение элементов на экране

Tags: java, android

Есть у нас приложение на андроид, у которого на фоне стоит картинка в PNG формате на которой в центре расположены 3 квадрата. Мне нужно создать 3 кнопки, которые были прям в центре этих квадраотв. Как это реализовать так, что бы на разных экранах ничего не слетело? [image: На первом экране пустые квадраты- это не View а сам рисунок фона]

Answer (score 1):

Используйте ConstraintLayout и привяжите кнопки к нужным сторонам квадратов (верх кнопки к верху квадрата низ к низу и т.д.)

Comment: Эти квадраты - это просто рисунки на фоне, не элементы, как можно привязать у ним кнопку?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать TableLayout (с параметром android:stretchColumns="*") внутри которого запихните TableRow в котором можно впихнуть уже ваши элементы